# Querying CosmosDB based on timestamps

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am working with a CosmosDB setup by one of my colleagues and connecting to it using a connection string. The database contains several JSON documents with the following schema:

```
{
    "period": "Raw",
    "source": "Traffic",
    "batchId": "ee737270-0b72-49b7-a2f1-201f642e9c81",
    "periodName": "Raw",
    "sourceName": "Traffic",
    "groupKey": "gc4151_a",
    "partitionKey": "traffic-gc4151_a-raw-raw",
    "time": "2021-08-05T23:55:10",
    "minute": 55,
    "hour": 23,
    "day": 05,
    "month": 08,
    "quarter": 3,
    "year": 2021,
    "minEventTime": "2021-08-05T23:55:09",
    "maxEventTime": "2021-08-05T23:55:11",
    "meta": {
        "siteId": "GC4151_A",
        "from": {
            "lat": "55.860894822588506",
            "long": "-4.284365958508686"
        },
        "to": {
            "lat": "55.86038667864348",
            "long": "-4.2826901232101795"
        }
    },
    "measurements": {
        "flow": [
            {
                "calculation": "Raw",
                "name": "flow",
                "calculationName": "Raw",
                "value": 0
            }
        ],
        "concentration": [
            {
                "calculation": "Raw",
                "name": "concentration",
                "calculationName": "Raw",
                "value": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    "added": "2021-08-05T12:21:32.000819Z",
    "updated": "2021-08-05T12:21:32.000819Z",
    "id": "d4346f50-543e-4c4d-82cf-835b480914c2",
    "_rid": "4RRTAIYVA1AIAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/4RRTAA==/colls/4RRTAIYVA1A=/docs/4RRTAIYVA1AIAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"1c0015a1-0000-1100-0000-5f3fbc4c0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1598012492
}
```

I am trying to write a SQL query to select all the records that fall between the current date-time and one week earlier, so I can use these to perform future calculations.

I have attempted to use both of the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE c.time > date_sub(now(), interval 1 week);
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE c.time >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY);
```

However, both of these return the following error:

```
Gateway Failed to Retrieve Query Plan: Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":124,"end":125},"code":"SC1001","message":"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '1'."}]}
ActivityId: 51c3b6f7-e760-4062-bd80-8cc9f8de5352, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0
```

My question is what is the issue with my code, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`DateTimeAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-datetimeadd) and [`GetCurrentDateTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-getcurrentdatetime) to achieve this. Eg.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE c.time > DateTimeAdd("day",-7,GetCurrentDateTime() )
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Yes, thank you that seems to work fine. The only issue is how does the speed scale if working with a massive dataset?

Comment: Your follow up is issue is difficult to respond to without more details. However, you can always use best design practices when working with cosmos db and monitor performance with growth. Here are a few articles to continue this process [article 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-query-metrics) and [article 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/profile-sql-api-query) and [article 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy)